# rspec filter with tag - do not run code in `describe`

Tags: ruby, rspec, tags

I got a rspec test that look something like this:

```
require 'rspec'

describe 'describe', :mytag do
  puts("inside describe")

  it 'test', :mytag do
    puts 'test'
  end
end
```

I want to be able to skip this whole spec file (and part inside `describe`) if I specify some other tag like this:

`rspec test_spec.rb --tag other`

But code inisde `describe` is executed and output `inside describe`

Is there any way to filter this code out?

I know I can change my code to something like this:

```
require 'rspec'

describe 'describe', :mytag do
  before(:all) do
     puts("inside describe")
  end

  it 'test', :mytag do
    puts 'test'
  end
end
```

But this require a lot changes in a lot of files, so I'm in search of simpler solution.

Comment: you can use`--exlude-pattern` flag and exclude file, also to exclude just tag you can use `~`  like: `rspec --exlude-pattern '**/filename.rb' --tag ~tag`

Comment: @noname I don't think it's right solution. This will not run any test. Like `rspec --tag mytag` will not run any test

Comment: yeah I just miss understand question and I edited my comment

Comment: Hm, not exactly that I want, but you gave me idea, that I can solve my problem by only including files I want to run by `--pattern` and just filter tests inside those files by tag

Comment: I am glad I could help somehow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution is not elegant, but get job done effectively (thanks @noname for pointing me for direction of solution)

I create a new rake task, that filter files with specified tag and after that create subprocess to run only filtered specs (and like rspec `--fail-fast` fails on first failure (as I need it)

like this

```
  files_with_tag = `grep -Ril spec/ -e ':mytag'`.split("\n")
  files_with_tag.each do |current_file|
    result = `rspec #{current_file} --tag mytag`
    puts(result)
    exit unless result.include?('0 failures')
  end
```